Inconsistency if a matrix is a function? (Hoffman Linear Algebra definition of matrices)
I have studied linear algebra from the book Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze. Now I'm seeing functions of matrices and I found that the definition of matrices in the book is weird. It says

An $m \times n$ matrix over the field $F$ is a function $A$ from the set of pairs of integers $(i, j), 1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n,$ into the field $F$. The entries of the matrix $A$ are the scalars $A(i, j)=A_{i j}$

For simplicity, let $F = \mathbb{R}$. So, we can compose any matrix $A$ with a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$. For example, let $f(x) = x^2$ and $A$ be a square matrix, then
\begin{align*}
(f \circ A)(i,j) = f(A(i,j)) = f(A_{ij}) = A_{ij}^2
\end{align*}
In other words, $A^2 = (A_{ij}^2)$. Wich contradicts the definition of matrix product. In general, if $f$ is any function defined on (all) $\mathbb{R}$, $f(A)$ is a matrix and its entries are $f(A_{ij})$. Wich clearly is not true.
I don't know if I'm making some mistakes, if it is the case, I don't know where.

Why do you think we should use the symbol $A^2$ to denote $f\circ A$?

This is just a formal definition of what a matrix is.  There is no claim that this representation respects function composition or matrix multiplication in some way.

@Nothingspecial it is natural write $f \circ A =  f(A) = A^2$ I think if $f(x) = x^2$

@Hilbert'sMinion Why? $f$ is a function on $\mathbb R$ so how does $f(A)=A^2$ make sense? I would like to define $A^2$ as the function which maps an $(i,j)$ ($1\leq i,j\leq n$) pair to $\sum_{k=1}^n A(i,k)\cdot A(k,i)$.

@Randall I know that. But if a matrix is a function then the composition is well defined. Multiplication was just an example, it could be any other function, for example exponential. To calculate $e^A$, we expand in Taylor series to calculate its value

But again,the claim is not that this will respect operations, so why do you think that $f \circ A$ should be $A^2$?

@Hilbert'sMinion Again, you asume that the symbol $e^A$ is used to denote $\exp\circ A$. The authors may just define $e^A$ using Taylor series while they define $\exp\circ A$ as the component wise exponentiation.

@Nothingspecial Ok ok, is just confusing, it is natural to me write $e^A$ to denote the composition. Or more general $f(A)$ for any function

@Randall I think that the confusion comes from the fact that if $f(x) = x^2$ and $g$ is another real function, we usually write $f \circ g = g^2$ or $f(g(x)) = [g(x)]^2$

It is not clear how you made the leap to $A^2 = (A_{ij}^2)$. The matrix of squares is not (in general) the square of a matrix.

@Hilbert'sMinion  You are right about that, and that is why $f\circ A$ is the matrix of squared entries of $A$, not the entries of $A^2$.

@copper.hat I understand now. My mistake was assuming $f \circ A = A^2$
